# Lightning Message service error in visualforce page - Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, sforce, lightning-message-service

Was anybody able to work with `sforce.one.subscribe` for subscribing to lightning message service in visualforce? I keep getting below error:

[image]

Even after including sforce and ajax js files, `sforce.one` is always undefined.

Page:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false">

    <apex:includeScript value="/sforce/one/49.0/api.js"></apex:includeScript>
    <apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/49.0/connection.js"></apex:includeScript>
    <apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/49.0/apex.js"></apex:includeScript>

    <apex:slds />
    <div>
        <p>Subscribe to SampleMessageChannel</p>
        <button onclick="subscribe_Message_Channel()">Subscribe</button>
        <div id="subscMessage" style="color:red"></div>

        <p>Unsubscribe from SampleMessageChannel</p>
        <button onclick="unsubscribe_Message_Channel()">Unsubscribe</button>
        <div id="unsubscMessage" style="color:red"></div>

        <p>Publish a message from VF</p>
        <button onclick="publishMC()">Publish</button>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <p>Received message:</p>
        <textarea id="MCMessageTextArea" rows="10" style="disabled:true;resize:none;width:100%;" />
    </div>
    <script>

        // Load the MessageChannel token in a variable
        var SAMPLEMC = "{!$MessageChannel.GenericChannel__c}";
        var subscriptionToMC;

        function onMCPublished(message) {
            var textArea = document.querySelector("#MCMessageTextArea");
            textArea.innerHTML = message ? JSON.stringify(message, null, '\t') : 'no message payload';
        }

        function subscribe_Message_Channel() {
            if (!subscriptionToMC) {
                subscriptionToMC = sforce.one.subscribe(SAMPLEMC, onMCPublished);
                var divAr = document.querySelector("#subscMessage");
                divAr.innerHTML = 'Message Channel Subscribed! ';
                var divAr = document.querySelector("#unsubscMessage");
                divAr.innerHTML = '';

            }
        }

        function unsubscribe_Message_Channel() {
            if (subscriptionToMC) {
                sforce.one.unsubscribe(subscriptionToMC);
                subscriptionToMC = null;
                var divAr = document.querySelector("#unsubscMessage");
                divAr.innerHTML = 'Message Channel UnSubscribed! ';
                var divAr = document.querySelector("#subscMessage");
                divAr.innerHTML = '';
            }
        }

        function publishMC() {
            const payload = {
                detail: 'some payload'
            }
            sforce.one.publish(SAMPLEMC, payload);
        }

    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Based on your comment [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/315877/window-postmessage-is-not-working-in-lightning-experience-but-working-in-lightni#comment469560_315877), this is probably not working because you're in mobile.

Comment: This question is not regarding mobile.. Even in desktop, I am unable to make it work. Not sure what I am missing

Comment: Is your page included in a Lightning Experience via iframes, including <wave:dashboard>, <apex:iframe>, and the standard HTML <iframe> tag?

Comment: LWC comp is just on record page. And vf page is in it as iframe

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not supported, per [the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/message_channel_considerations.htm). You'd need to move your VF page to a VF page component.